# how to run spring-boot integration tests with multiple embeded servers with gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, integration-testing

i have some integration tests for my spring boot application. based on dependencies (and classpath jars) spring boot chooses a server to start: (tomcat is there is only spring-boot-starter-web, undertow if there is spring-boot-starter-undertow or jetty if there is spring-boot-starter-jetty)

i'm writing a filter that is supposed to work on many different servers. i don't have compile dependency on any server but i would like to test my code on many servers. how can i do it?

for sure one way is to make gradle script set dependencies based on some env variable and then just call `gradle test` a few times with different env variable values. is there any simpler way, so i can test everything at once? like starting the servers programmatically in tests? or using some gradle/spring plugin?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add test-scoped dependencies for all three servers but create three separate Spring Boot application classes in your test code, each application class disabling the `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration` and importing the appropriate server's configuration:

```
@Profile("tomcat")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)
@Import(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat.class)
public class TomcatApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TomcatApplication.run(TomcatApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Profile("undertow")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)
@Import(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedUndertow.class)
public class UndertowApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UndertowApplication.run(UndertowApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Profile("jetty")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)
@Import(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty.class)
public class JettyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JettyApplication.run(JettyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then, write your test with the appropriate `@ActiveProfiles` set and you should be ready to go.